# Invisible delimiter not rendered correctiy with STIX Two

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, delimiters

I am currently using `unicode-math` STIX Two Math fonts, and XeLaTeX. I found that the invisible delimiter cannot be rendered correctly:
[image: A boxed question mark]

Here's the code:

```
\[h(x)=\begin{cases}
     1, & \mbox{if } \exists n\in\mathbb{N}_+\text{ such that }x=\nicefrac{1}{n} \\
     0, & \mbox{otherwise}
   \end{cases}.\]

\[h(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
  1, & \mbox{if } \exists n\in\mathbb{N}_+\text{ such that }x=\nicefrac{1}{n} \\
  0, & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right..
\]
```

How should I remove that question mark?

Thank you.

--Update

Here's a full code excerpt.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont {STIX2Text-Regular}[
    Extension=.otf,
    BoldFont=STIX2Text-Bold,
    ItalicFont=STIX2Text-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=STIX2Text-BoldItalic,
]
\setmonofont{Courier Prime Code.ttf}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[StylisticSet=02, StylisticSet=08]
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[range={\oplus, \otimes}, StylisticSet=16]
%\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{dutchcal}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{leftidx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mattens}
\usepackage[e]{esvect}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{minted}

\title{STIX Two Test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\[h(x)=\begin{cases}
     1, & \mbox{if } \exists n\in\mathbb{N}_+\text{ such that 
}x=\nicefrac{1}{n} \\
     0, & \mbox{otherwise}
   \end{cases}.\]

\[
h(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1, & \mbox{if } \exists n\in\mathbb{N}_+\text{ such that }x=\nicefrac{1}{n} \\
0, & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right..
\]

\end{document}
```

Here's log

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
    \vbox(655.63496+0.0)x435.61176
    .\special{papersize=597.50793pt,845.04694pt}
    .\glue -25.16531
    .\vbox(680.80028+0.0)x418.25555, shifted 17.3562
    ..\vbox(17.0+0.0)x418.25555, glue set 17.0fil
    ...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x418.25555
    ....\special{color push gray 0}
    ....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x418.25555
    ....\special{color pop}
    ..\glue 20.40001
    ..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
    ..\vbox(595.80026+0.0)x418.25555, glue set 357.54204fil
    ...\write-{}
    ...\special{color push gray 0}
    ...\write-{}
    ...\glue(\topskip) 11.0
    ...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
    ...\glue 21.9
    ...\glue -21.9
    ...\penalty -51
    ...\glue 21.9
    ...\special{color push gray 0}
    ...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
    ...\glue(\baselineskip) 10.19164
    ...\hbox(14.80836+0.29034)x418.25555, glue set 146.74184fil
    ....\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
    .....\glue 0.0
    .....\glue 0.0
    .....\glue -5.47499
    .....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
    ......\special{color push gray 0}
    ......\special{color pop}
    .....\glue 5.47499
    ....\penalty 0
    ....\TU/Cabin(0)/bx/n/20.74 STIX
    ....\glue 4.6665 plus 2.33092 minus 1.55705
    ....\TU/Cabin(0)/bx/n/20.74 Two
    ....\glue 4.6665 plus 2.33325 minus 1.5555
    ....\TU/Cabin(0)/bx/n/20.74 Test
    ....\penalty 10000
    ....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0
    ....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ...\special{color pop}
    ...\glue 5.47499
    ...\glue 10.95
    ...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
    ...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.10971
    ...\hbox(12.59995+5.40005)x418.25555, glue set 203.12778fil
    ....\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
    ....\hbox(12.59995+5.40005)x12.0
    .....\mathon
    .....\vbox(12.59995+5.40005)x12.0
    ......\hbox(12.59995+5.40005)x12.0
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    .......\hbox(12.59995+5.40005)x12.0
    ........\rule(12.59995+5.40005)x0.0
    ........\glue 6.0
    ........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ........\glue 6.0
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    .....\mathoff
    ....\penalty 10000
    ....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0
    ....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ...\glue 10.95
    ...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
    ...\glue(\baselineskip) 3.13914
    ...\hbox(9.4608+2.04478)x418.25555, glue set 168.10939fil
    ....\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
    ....\TU/STIX2Text-Regular(0)/m/n/14.4 June
    ....\glue 3.384 plus 1.692 minus 1.12799
    ....\TU/STIX2Text-Regular(0)/m/n/14.4 21,
    ....\glue 3.384 plus 2.11499 minus 0.90239
    ....\TU/STIX2Text-Regular(0)/m/n/14.4 2018
    ....\penalty 10000
    ....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0
    ....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ...\glue 0.0 plus 10.95
    ...\penalty -51
    ...\glue 12.0 plus 4.0 minus 6.0
    ...\glue 21.9
    ...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
    ...\glue(\baselineskip) 11.55522
    ...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x418.25555, glue set 407.30556fil
    ....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x10.95
    ....\penalty 10000
    ....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
    ...\penalty 10000
    ...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
    ...\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
    ...\hbox(19.14507+13.4948)x200.04408, shifted 109.10574, display
    ....\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1224
    ....\kern0.219
    ....\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1064
    ....\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#3354
    ....\kern0.3285
    ....\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1065
    ....\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04169 plus 3.04169
    ....\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1202
    ....\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04169 plus 3.04169
    ....\hbox(19.14507+13.4948)x160.86252
    .....\vbox(18.5931+12.6582)x4.76324, shifted 0.14232
    ......\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1356
    .....\vbox(19.14507+13.4948)x149.47452
    ......\hbox(11.42392+4.89601)x149.47452
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    .......\hbox(11.42392+4.89601)x19.11868
    ........\rule(11.42392+4.89601)x0.0
    ........\mathon
    ........\mathoff
    ........\mathon
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1138
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1048
    ........\mathoff
    ........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ........\mathon
    ........\glue 10.95
    ........\mathoff
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    .......\hbox(11.42392+4.89601)x130.35583
    ........\mathon
    ........\hbox(7.80734+0.0)x9.05563
    .........\TU/STIX2Text-Regular(0)/m/n/10.95 if
    .........\glue 2.57324 plus 1.28662 minus 0.85774
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1623
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#3341
    ........\kern0.219
    ........\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04169 plus 3.04169
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1629
    ........\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04169 plus 3.04169
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(3)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1230
    ........\hbox(4.54568+0.36858)x6.328, shifted 2.29953
    .........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/7.67853 glyph#4532
    ........\hbox(7.7307+0.12044)x47.96097
    .........\hbox(7.7307+0.12044)x47.96097
    ..........\glue 2.57324 plus 1.28662 minus 0.85774
    ..........\TU/STIX2Text-Regular(0)/m/n/10.95 such
    ..........\glue 2.57324 plus 1.28662 minus 0.85774
    ..........\TU/STIX2Text-Regular(0)/m/n/10.95 that
    ..........\glue 2.57324 plus 1.28662 minus 0.85774
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#3354
    ........\kern0.3285
    ........\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04169 plus 3.04169
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1202
    ........\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04169 plus 3.04169
    ........\hbox(6.87166+0.0)x4.30765
    .........\hbox(5.29051+0.0)x4.30765, shifted -1.58115
    ..........\mathon
    ..........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/7.67853 glyph#4523
    ..........\mathoff
    ........\kern -1.21667
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1060
    ........\kern -0.60834
    ........\hbox(4.22319+0.09215)x5.60533
    .........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/7.67853 glyph#4686
    ........\mathoff
    ........\mathon
    ........\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
    ........\mathoff
    ........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ........\mathon
    ........\mathoff
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    ......\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
    ......\hbox(11.42392+4.89601)x149.47452
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    .......\hbox(11.42392+4.89601)x19.11868
    ........\rule(11.42392+4.89601)x0.0
    ........\mathon
    ........\mathoff
    ........\mathon
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1137
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1048
    ........\mathoff
    ........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ........\mathon
    ........\glue 10.95
    ........\mathoff
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    .......\hbox(11.42392+4.89601)x130.35583, glue set 84.98999fil
    ........\mathon
    ........\hbox(7.7307+0.12044)x45.36584
    .........\TU/STIX2Text-Regular(0)/m/n/10.95 otherwise
    ........\mathoff
    ........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ........\mathon
    ........\mathoff
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    .....\vbox(8.59575+1.85056)x6.62476, shifted 0.54747
    ......\TU/STIX2Math.otf(3)/m/n/10.95 glyph#0
    ....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.82501
    ....\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1052
    ...\penalty 0
    ...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.5 plus 3.5 minus 3.0
    ...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
    ...\glue(\baselineskip) 0.10521
    ...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x418.25555, glue set 407.30556fil
    ....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x10.95
    ....\penalty 10000
    ....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
    ...\penalty 10000
    ...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
    ...\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
    ...\hbox(16.42513+10.77486)x208.7656, shifted 104.74498, display
    ....\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1224
    ....\kern0.219
    ....\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1064
    ....\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#3354
    ....\kern0.3285
    ....\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1065
    ....\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04169 plus 3.04169
    ....\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1202
    ....\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04169 plus 3.04169
    ....\hbox(16.42513+10.77486)x169.58403
    .....\vbox(15.94319+10.0083)x4.43475, shifted 0.14232
    ......\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1354
    .....\vbox(16.42513+10.77486)x158.52452
    ......\hbox(9.51996+4.08003)x158.52452
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    .......\hbox(9.51996+4.08003)x18.16869
    ........\rule(9.51996+4.08003)x0.0
    ........\glue 5.0
    ........\mathon
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1138
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1048
    ........\mathoff
    ........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ........\glue 5.0
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    .......\hbox(9.51996+4.08003)x140.35583
    ........\glue 5.0
    ........\mathon
    ........\hbox(7.80734+0.0)x9.05563
    .........\TU/STIX2Text-Regular(0)/m/n/10.95 if
    .........\glue 2.57324 plus 1.28662 minus 0.85774
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1623
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#3341
    ........\kern0.219
    ........\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04169 plus 3.04169
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1629
    ........\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04169 plus 3.04169
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(3)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1230
    ........\hbox(4.54568+0.36858)x6.328, shifted 2.29953
    .........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/7.67853 glyph#4532
    ........\hbox(7.7307+0.12044)x47.96097
    .........\hbox(7.7307+0.12044)x47.96097
    ..........\glue 2.57324 plus 1.28662 minus 0.85774
    ..........\TU/STIX2Text-Regular(0)/m/n/10.95 such
    ..........\glue 2.57324 plus 1.28662 minus 0.85774
    ..........\TU/STIX2Text-Regular(0)/m/n/10.95 that
    ..........\glue 2.57324 plus 1.28662 minus 0.85774
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#3354
    ........\kern0.3285
    ........\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04169 plus 3.04169
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1202
    ........\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04169 plus 3.04169
    ........\hbox(6.87166+0.0)x4.30765
    .........\hbox(5.29051+0.0)x4.30765, shifted -1.58115
    ..........\mathon
    ..........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/7.67853 glyph#4523
    ..........\mathoff
    ........\kern -1.21667
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1060
    ........\kern -0.60834
    ........\hbox(4.22319+0.09215)x5.60533
    .........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/7.67853 glyph#4686
    ........\mathoff
    ........\mathon
    ........\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
    ........\mathoff
    ........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ........\glue 5.0
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    ......\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
    ......\hbox(9.51996+4.08003)x158.52452
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    .......\hbox(9.51996+4.08003)x18.16869
    ........\rule(9.51996+4.08003)x0.0
    ........\glue 5.0
    ........\mathon
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1137
    ........\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1048
    ........\mathoff
    ........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ........\glue 5.0
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    .......\hbox(9.51996+4.08003)x140.35583, glue set 84.98999fil
    ........\glue 5.0
    ........\mathon
    ........\hbox(7.7307+0.12044)x45.36584
    .........\TU/STIX2Text-Regular(0)/m/n/10.95 otherwise
    ........\mathoff
    ........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ........\glue 5.0
    .......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
    .....\vbox(8.59575+1.85056)x6.62476, shifted 0.54747
    ......\TU/STIX2Math.otf(3)/m/n/10.95 glyph#0
    ....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.82501
    ....\TU/STIX2Math.otf(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#1052
    ...\penalty 0
    ...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.5 plus 3.5 minus 3.0
    ...\glue -5.5
    ...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ...\glue 0.0
    ...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
    ..\glue(\baselineskip) 40.60295
    ..\hbox(6.99706+0.0)x418.25555
    ...\special{color push gray 0}
    ...\hbox(6.99706+0.0)x418.25555
    ....\hbox(6.99706+0.0)x418.25555
    .....\vbox(6.99706+0.0)x418.25555
    ......\hbox(6.99706+0.0)x418.25555, glue set 206.41766fil
    .......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    .......\special{color push gray 0}
    .......\TU/STIX2Text-Regular(0)/m/n/10.95 1
    .......\special{color pop}
    .......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
    ....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
    ...\special{color pop}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can't reproduce the issue. Can you please turn the code snippet into a full (minimal) example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: Hi. I have added an example.

Comment: I see no problem with the example code.

Comment: can you add `\showoutput` and then show the relevant page output from the log (all the lines starting with `.....`

Comment: I get the /.notdef markers with texlive 2016, but they are gone in texlive 2018.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know if this is what you want.